# SOAP in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using SOAP in my application. In  that i am receiving error.

The following is the structure of my request.

```
 <Search xmlns="URL">
              <authentication>
                <LoginID>string</LoginID>
                <Password>string</Password>
              </authentication>
              <ID>int</ID>
              <iD>int</iD>
              <dojStr>string</dojStr>
              <Data>
                <Keys>
                  <KPOfStringString>
                    <V>string</V>
                    <K>string</K>
                  </KPOfStringString>
                  <KPOfStringString>
                    <V>string</V>
                    <K>string</K>
                  </KPOfStringString>
                </Keys>
                <SortKeys>
                  <KPOfStringString>
                    <V>string</V>
                    <K>string</K>
                  </KPOfStringString>
                  <KPOfStringString>
                    <V>string</V>
                    <K>string</K>
                  </KPOfStringString>
                </SortKeys>
                <No>int</No>
                <Size>int</Size>
              </Data>
            </Search>
          </soap:Body>
```

The following is the way i am setting input for this.Is this the correct way,because i am receiving some error.

```
                PropertyInfo usrid =new PropertyInfo();
            usrid.setName("LoginID");
        usrid.setValue(userid);
        usrid.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(usrid);

            PropertyInfo pass =new PropertyInfo();
            pass.setName("Password");
            pass.setValue(password);
        pass.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pass);

                PropertyInfo Id =new PropertyInfo();
        sourceid.setName("ID");
            sourceid.setValue(string value);
        sourceid.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(Id);

            PropertyInfo id =new PropertyInfo();
            destid.setName("id");
            destid.setValue(string value);
            destid.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(id);

                PropertyInfo dte =new PropertyInfo();
            dte.setName("dojStr");
            dte.setValue(date);
            dte.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(dte);

                PropertyInfo page =new PropertyInfo();
            page.setName("V");  
            page.setName("K");   
            page.setValue(null);
            page.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(page); 

                PropertyInfo no =new PropertyInfo();
            pageno.setName("no");           
        pageno.setValue(1);
            pageno.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(no);

            PropertyInfo size =new PropertyInfo();
            pagesize.setName("size");           
            pagesize.setValue(10);
            pagesize.setType(int.class);
        request.addProperty(size);
```

It shows Following error:

```
 05-10 12:39:30.027: W/System.err(469): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

05-10 12:39:30.027: W/System.err(469):    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
05-10 12:39:30.027: W/System.err(469):    at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
05-10 12:39:30.027: W/System.err(469):    at System.Int64.Parse(String s)
05-10 12:39:30.037: W/System.err(469):
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I suppose this `Value cannot be null.` part of the error might have something to do with this `page.setValue(null);` part of your code?

Comment: If i suppose give some string value ,also it shows error.

Comment: Use dichotomy, remove half of your properties, then find the bad half, the remove half of it..and so on until you find the culprit property

Comment: Hi Snicolas thanks..But how its possibel ,if suppose i am removing half of the property means the request is missing some input in that case it will show faulty error.

Answer (score 0):

destid.setType(int.class); <- Isnt int in Java a simple Type?

Have you tryed destid.setType(Integer.class); ?

Comment: Have you tryed in Addition to passing a String through page.setValue() except of null?